# Оздоровьте или оздоровите?

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы, управление, спряжение

Фраза: *оздоровьте органы.*
Важно понимать, существует ли вообще слово "оздоровьте" и уместно ли его здесь применять?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрим склонение:
[оздорови́ть](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) — *оздорови́те* (будущее время), *оздорови́те* (повелительное наклонение).
(Оздоровьте — неверно.)

Точно так же склоняются глаголы *хранить, обновить* (то есть ударение в будущем времени и повелительном наклонении совпадают).

Посмотрим значение и управление:
[оздоровить](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C), *кого-что*. Сделать здоровым, более здоровым. *Спорт оздоровил детей. О. организм водными процедурами. О. окружающую среду. О. обстановку в коллективе. О. экономику. О. работу школы.*
Еще у Ожегова: улучшить, привести в нормальное, благоприятное состояние; улучшить санитарное состояние чего-нибудь.

Оздоровите — организм, тело, органы, человечество.

*— Поезжайте! **Оздоровите ребенка!** А уж потом я своими овощами-фруктами в Подмосковье окончательно укреплю ее иммунитет* (Л. Райт).